# Why does local host say "It Works"?

Tags: mac, virtualhost, localhost

I have configured all my websites in the "Sites" folder to be tested in my browser. When I type a web address for example http://test.dev, I get "It Works".

Why?

Comment: Because you haven't configured it to say anything else?

Answer (score 17):

That's the default Apache HTTP index page.  It's there to indicate you've correctly installed and enabled httpd.

Comment: In other words, because "It Works".

Comment: Past few hours I have been trying to remove this page. Even after removing httpd, it is still showing.

Answer (score 10):

That page is located in `/Library/Webserver/Documents`.

You need to make sure you uncomment the second line of the following:

```
# User home directories
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

That file then includes the files in `/private/etc/apache2/users`

There should be one with your username.

You can then go to `localhost/~username`, which is equivalent of visiting `Users/username/Sites`

Comment: or uncomment this line `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Comment: That is the default page location. But it's not the page being posted. Use apachectl -S to find the location of the Main DocumentRoot

Answer (score 4):

This probably means that you don't have a specific entry in your web server configuration for for the IP address (if using IP-based virtual hosting) or the name you are trying to reach (test.dev, in your example, if using name-based virtual hosting).

For example, in Apache you can create `<VirtualHost>` sections which specify the document root for requests that match the IP and/or name (again, depending on if you're doing IP or name based virtuals).  If none of those match, it will fall back to the DocumentRoot and other settings that are set **outside** of the `<VirtualHost>` entries.

So, to resolve it you could either make the virtual host config for the site that you want to receive these requests include this name/IP that isn't currently matching (preferable) or make one of your sites existing in the main config instead of in a `<VirtualHost>` (or similar depending on the web server you are using) section.

Answer (score 3):

Use `apachectl -S` (mac) to list the loaded configuration and to see all your loaded virtual hosts. Probably your project's `.conf` file is not in that list.